# CI: Best practice for use same function in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have class name *Deal* and have function inside it which name is *addit*

```
class Deal extends CI_Controller {
   public function addit() {
      //my function
   }
}
```

And I have another controller name *Public* and I want to use function *addit* which belong to class Deal by extend it.

```
class Public extends Deal {
       public function addit() {
          //my function
       }
}
```

I quite new in Codeigniter and just read few references, looking at another question on this site, and already had some answers, but I dont know which one is the **best practice** for  it, here some solution I found:

1.Create *Deal* file and save at application/libraries function so another controller can use its function.

2.Create *addit* function on application/helper so we can use its function anywhere.

3.Create *Deal* file in application/core so other controller can use its function.

My question is, what is the best practice for solving my problem, and are there any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what type of function we are talking about here.
If it is about really simple function which don't do any db access or have interaction with CI components, you can create an helper :

Quote from the codeigniter documentation :

> Helpers are not written in an Object Oriented format. They are **simple**,
>   **procedural functions**. Each helper function performs one specific task,
>   with no dependence on other functions.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

---

However, if it's a relatively complex code, then you should consider writing a library :

In application/libraries create Tools.php (or whatever you want)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Tools
{
  protected $ci;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance(); 
        //Allows you to access CI components
    }

    public function myfunction($data)
    {
       //If you want to use codeigniter's functionalities :
       //use $this->ci->function()
    }

}
```

And then in your controllers :

```
$this->load->library("tools");
$this->tools->myfunction($data);
```

If your library is meant to be used very often, you can load it once for all in config/autoload.php :

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'tools', '...');
```

CI doc about libraries : http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

---

Option 3 doesn't fit your problematic as you are not extending CI itself.

From comments : As the name suggests, "core" is for improving CI's core. If you don't like the way CI  handles sessions for example, then you can write a new core class, however, if it's about your user management system then it concerns your app and not the framework and should be done in a lib.

Comment: ok sir, i got your point for library and helper, but I dont get it when you said option 3 doesn't fit, is it bad if I create class Deal inside application/core and another controller use Deal class?

Comment: As the name suggests, "core" is for improving CI's core. If you don't like the way CI  handles sessions for example, then you can write a new core class, however, if it's about your user management system then it concerns your app and not the framework and should be done in a lib.

Comment: @AdrienXL Would you please explain more about `$this->ci =& get_instance()` , Thanks :)

Comment: @vahidnajafi Basically, when you are working inside classes that extends CI_Controller or CI_Model then you can use $this to access members of your class parents. However, in a lib, you extend nothing so you don't have access to $this as you know it. Thanks to CI's implementation of the singleton pattern you are able to retrieve the magical $this with get_instance(). Hope it's clear.