# how to make one global function in code igniter?

Tags: php, function, rest, codeigniter, curl

I am using rest api's in my website..for that i have to make curl requests in every controller many times like that....

```
$data = array('id' => '01','user_name' => 'abc');
$data_json = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://abc.xyz.com/1.0/index.php/abc_ctrl/function");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$output3 = json_decode($output);
```

functionality of every curl is same, like it makes a post call by sending a post data to rest controller.....
i am tired of using same lines every time everyware...I want to make a post request function in config file or i dont know in main file, which accept parameter as url and post data and returns output...

so everytime i have to call that function in config and i got results...

Comment: maybe interesting? [CodeIgniter : Create Own Helper](https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-create-helper/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CI: Best practice for use same function in controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697922/ci-best-practice-for-use-same-function-in-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do it like this:

```
public function FunctionName()
  {
    $data = array('id' => '01','user_name' => 'abc');
    $url = "http://abc.xyz.com/1.0/index.php/abc_ctrl/function";
    $result = $this->CurlAPI($data,$url);
  }

  public function CurlAPI($data,$url)
  {
    $data_json = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $output3 = json_decode($output);
    return $output3;
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

You may also write this function in helper file as:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


    public function CurlAPI($data,$url)
      {
        $data_json = json_encode($data);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $output3 = json_decode($output);
        return $output3;
      }
```

Save this to application/helpers/ . We shall call it "new_helper.php"

This can be in your controller, model or view (not preferable)

```
$this->load->helper('new_helper');

echo CurlAPI($data,$url);
```